# Is there a difference between dynamic code analysis tools and dynamic testing tools?

Tags: testing, dynamic

I'm looking for dynamic analysis/testing tools.

But I'm very confused about the used terms. What exactly is dynamic code analysis? Is there a difference between **dynamic code analysis** and **dynamic testing**? I have the feeling that these two terms are mixed.

Comment: Hi N/A. - can you explain what you are looking for, and why? If you aren't sure what the terms mean, how will you know what to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: They are synonyms.

[Dynamic Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_testing) (also known as [Dynamic Program Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis)) is achieved by actually executing the code to ensure its quality. This can be in the shape of Manual Tests (e.g. User Acceptance Testing) or Automated Tests (Unit/Integration Tests using Junit or Nunit for example).

On the opposite side, [Static Program Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) analyses the code without actually running it. It can still reveal quality issues that Dynamic Analysis cannot detect. For example,  high [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), code duplication, potential bugs etc.